# Unable to take Screenshot using Taskt RPA

Tags: rpa

I am using TaskT rpa for an automation code however, the code is working except that the screenshot part, every time it fails on screenshot step, and throw an error on a log. I have add the image with steps detail with the quesiton

```html
Error: System.Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename)
   at taskt.Core.AutomationCommands.ScreenshotCommand.RunCommand(Object sender)
   at taskt.Core.AutomationEngineInstance.ExecuteCommand(ScriptAction command)
   at taskt.Core.AutomationEngineInstance.ExecuteCommand(ScriptAction command)
   at taskt.Core.AutomationEngineInstance.ExecuteScript(String filePath)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1zgj.png)

Comment: Better off creating an issue https://github.com/saucepleez/taskt/issues/new

Answer (score 1):

This is ready G1ANT's code which you can use:

```
keyboard ⋘ctrl+printscreen⋙
program mspaint.exe
keyboard ⋘ctrl+v⋙
keyboard ⋘ctrl+s⋙
keyboard filename
change the file name and on the end, you can put the last command:
keyboard ⋘enter⋙
```